# The css file is downloaded to the local end, but the path format is wrong (Newbie question)

Tags: html, css, file, path, src

I download google's css file to use his cute icon

**I want to download them all to the local side, so that they can be used without the Internet, but the path format may be wrong**

The path of the original .css, css file name - "fonts.googleapis.com_icon_family=Material+Icons.css" refers to the same  "woff2" online

```css
/* fallback */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/materialicons/v140/flUhRq6tzZclQEJ-Vdg-IuiaDsNc.woff2) format('woff2');
}

.material-icons {
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 1;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  word-wrap: normal;
  direction: ltr;
  -webkit-font-feature-settings: 'liga';
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
```

---

- schematic diagram
  I currently have them both in the same folder
  [![schematic diagram][1]][1]

My absolute path is
"C:\Users\jason\Desktop\Website_Project_Before\iPortfolio\iPortfolio\main_online\download_style_to_local\css\KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmSU5fCRc4EsA.woff2"

Compared to the original code, I have tried

```css
/* fallback */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(flUhRq6tzZclQEJ-Vdg-IuiaDsNc.woff2) format('woff2');
}
```

and

```css
/* fallback */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(../download_style_to_local/css/flUhRq6tzZclQEJ-Vdg-IuiaDsNc.woff2) format('woff2');
}
```

and so on, but it seems that it is not the correct path, I need some advice
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ertgq.png

Answer (score 0):

here is the result [video](https://imgur.com/a/C5Ng26Z) (the second one)

1.download "https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/materialicons/v140/flUhRq6tzZclQEJ-Vdg-IuiaDsNc.woff2" and name"1.woff2" ，make sure put that in the same folder with your website html

2.put "https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"'s code directly inside html  tag

```
/* fallback */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(1.woff2) format('woff2');
}

.material-icons {
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 1;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  word-wrap: normal;
  direction: ltr;
  -webkit-font-feature-settings: 'liga';
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
```